# WPF: Add a button in a combobox defined in datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have this `ItemsControl` defined in my xaml

```
<ItemsControl Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding FirstProperty}"/>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SecondProperty}"/>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding ThirdProperty}"/>
                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding CBSource}" Grid.Column="2" Width="140" Visibility="{Binding HasCombobox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <Button Content="INeedAButtonHere"></Button>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I need to add to each `ComboBox` created in this way a `Button`, possibly placed on the bottom of the dropdown since the `ComboBox` has a source. My current code raise an exception (XamlParseError) when the `UserControl` is shown. How can be this done?

Comment: Do you want a Button for each item in the ComboBox? Or just a Button for each ComboBox?

Comment: Just a button for each ComboBox, placed at the bottom of the dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `CompositeCollection`:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding CBSource}" />
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Content="TEST"/>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SecondProperty}"/>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding ThirdProperty}"/>
            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Width="140" Visibility="{Binding HasCombobox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" />
                            <ComboBoxItem>
                                <Button Content="INeedAButtonHere"></Button>
                            </ComboBoxItem>
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I didn't even knew the existence of such tool. It works perfectly, thank you